# jQuery change element on select - global script for multiple select inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a form builder script. I have a select input where the user can select the form element they want to use, depending on their selection ("select", "checkbox" or "radio") another form field is displayed allowing users to input their options.

Users can create as many instances of form elements as they want, so each select input has a dynamically created id that corresponds to the id of the hidden form field. I then use jQuery to determine whether the "options" field should be hidden or not (triggered on change of the form elements select input).

Currently, for every instance, I have the following code addedabove the select input:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var arr = ['select', 'checkbox', 'radio'];
    var thisForm = 'select.input-type-118';

    function showHideSelect() {
      var val = $(thisForm + ' option:selected').val();
      var selectOptions = $('#select-options-118')

      if (arr.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
        selectOptions.show();
      } else {
        selectOptions.hide();
      }
    }

    showHideSelect();

      $(thisForm).change(function() {
        showHideSelect();
      });

  });

</script>
```

Where `var thisForm` and `var selectOptions` are added dynamically and refer to the select option below this script.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this rather than repeat several instances of this, at the moment, a users page cold look like this:

```
<script>
...
</script>

<select>
...
</select>

<textarea>
This is hidden depending on the select option
</textarea>

<script>
...
</script>

<select>
...
</select>

<textarea>
This is hidden depending on the select option
</textarea>

<script>
...
</script>

<select>
...
</select>

<textarea>
This is hidden depending on the select option
</textarea>

...etc...etc
```

My concern is that I don't think it's best practice to have so many instances of the same script, but I'm unsure how to write a global script that will allow me to show/hide the textarea on an individual basis.

I have shown a more accurate depiction of my workings on this jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/46stb05y/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Event Delegation` Concepts. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

With this you can change your code to

```
$(document).on('change','select',function() { //common to all your select items
    showHideSelect($(this));  // passing the select element which trigerred the change event
  });
```

This will work even on the select items that are added dynamically

You must change your function to receive the element as the parameter.

```
    function showHideSelect($selectElement) {      
    var val = $selectElement.val();
    var selectOptionsId =  $selectElement.attr('class').replace('input-type','select-options');
    var selectOptions = $("#"+selectOptionsId);

    if (arr.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
      selectOptions.show();
    } else {
      selectOptions.hide();
    }
  }
```

Here is the [Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/46stb05y/6/)

Comment: Thanks @Reddy. So the top script, do I repeat that for every instance and then just have one instance of the function?

Comment: No, even the top script is one time.

Comment: Just added to my JSFiddle and doesn't seem to work - perhaps I've added it wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/46stb05y/5/

Comment: @SamSkirrow I have updated my answer and linked to jsfiddle have a check

Comment: that looks great, although, how would I hide the ".select-options" when the page first loads? Should I just do this using CSS?

Comment: Yes CSS would be sufficient.

Comment: Glad it helped!! Happy coding